# Do TP regeneration abilities stack?

Tags: phantasy-star-online

Do the various TP regeneration abilities stack?

So would it make sense for a **FOnewearl** (which has TP generation as class ability) to wear the armor [**Spirit Garment**](http://www.pso-world.com/items.php?artid=104&op=viewarticle) ("calms the wearer's mind for gradual TP recovery") and **TP/Restorate** unit(s)?

Do these (are there others?) TP regeneration abilities work the same, or are they different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these abilities should all stack. Though it is important to know that many of these happen at different times.

The racial ability to regenerate TP only occurs while not performing any actions including moving (menu browsing is fine). TP/HP/PB restoration units only regenerate while moving. I have never owned Spirit Garment so I cannot confirm when its regeneration occurs, but it could be constant.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew the difference. I just saw that this seems to be explained in the [item description for the unit](http://www.pso-world.com/items.php?op=viewarticle&artid=391), but on PSO Blue Burst, the text seems to have changed (it no longer mentions "as you walk"). A quick test on BB confirmed that it still works while moving.